# How to trigger a combination of keypress once the website loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress

I have a input field what I want to do are once the website loads it will trigger a click on the input then arrow down and lastly enter I tried the code below but I'm not able to make it happen I'm just new in using key press,

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="location" class="location" id="destination-autocomplete" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">
```

**JS**

```
$('#destination-autocomplete').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));
$('#destination-autocomplete').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 40 }));
$('#destination-autocomplete').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in document ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#destination-autocomplete').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));
$('#destination-autocomplete').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 40 }));
$('#destination-autocomplete').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));
});
```

Comment: Thank you but still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should do this, even if you can.
It seems like you have or want some kind of autocomplete text field. In that case just modify the model of the autocomplete text field and do not try to preselect an item via key events.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using plain JS DOMContentLoaded:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  $('#destination-autocomplete').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));
  $('#destination-autocomplete').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 40 }));
  $('#destination-autocomplete').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));
})
```